# How to convert BMPs to RBG JPEGs

Tags: image, rgb, mogrify

I have a directory of BMP images. All the images are represented in the RGB color space, though some only actually contain black and white.

I need to convert the BMP to JPG images. All the JPG images also have to be in the RGB color space.

I ran

`mogrify -format jpg *.bmp`

This creates JPG images for each of my BMPs. However, the BMPs that contain just two colors end up as grayscale JPGs instead of RGB. I also tried

`mogrify -format jpg *.bmp -colorspace RGB`

and got the same thing.

How do covert a set of BMPs to JPGs and force the RGB color space?

*macOS 10.15.7*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. It's easy with Pillow.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

import sys

for filename in Path(sys.argv[1]).glob("*.bmp"):
    Image.open(filename).save(filename.with_suffix(".jpg"))
```

Comment: I didn't even know a grayscale JPG was possible.  You might want to be careful if Pillow expands their support to include it in the future.